# check if progressbar is filled

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a pvp simulator in C# and have ran into a problem with progressbars.
what im trying to do is: when one of the players attacks, a random number gets added to the progressbar. Once its full a radiobutton gets enabled and allows the player to do a special move. Here is the code:

```
Random r = new Random();            
int Minvalue = 1;
int Maxvalue = 20;
int Special = r.Next(Minvalue, Maxvalue);

attack.Hitplayer2();
int result = (SpecialBar1.Value + Special);


if (result < 100)
{
    SpecialBar1.Value = (SpecialBar1.Value + Special);
}
else if (result == 100)
{
    SpecialBar1.Enabled = true;
}
else if (result > 100)
{
    SpecialBar1.Value = 100;
}
```

For some reason if the result == 100 it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What is Special incrementing by? if more than on the you might need to rethink the addition part.  If you print result before the if statements I think you will find the problem

Comment: You should check against `SpecialBar1.Maximum` instead of 100.

Comment: i've tried using SpecialBar1.Maximum but it gives the same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if the result == 100 it doesn't work

Because the result will almost always be either more or less than 100. Make those checks first. Actually, you should have only one check for >= 100 instead of two separate checks. You want to do the same anyway.

```
Random r = new Random();            
int Minvalue = 1;
int Maxvalue = 20;
int Special = r.Next(Minvalue, Maxvalue);

attack.Hitplayer2();
int result = (SpecialBar1.Value + Special);

if (result < SpecialBar1.Maximum)
{
    SpecialBar1.Value = (SpecialBar1.Value + Special);
}
else
{
    SpecialBar1.Enabled = true;
    SpecialBar1.Value = SpecialBar1.Maximum;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to make the result something different than 100 otherwise this wont work ;)